# Property change in Base ViewModel with prism

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, prism

I'm using prism to develop an android app.

I'm trying to make a Base ViewModel. Inside this ViewModel I would like to set common properties to all my ViewModels.

```
  public class BaseViewModel : BindableBase
{
    protected INavigationService _navigationService;
    protected IPageDialogService _dialogService;

    public BaseViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dialogService = dialogService;
    }

    private string _common;
    /// <summary>
    /// Common property
    /// </summary>
    public string CommonProperty
    {
        get { return _common; }
        set
        {
            _common = value;
            SetProperty(ref _common, value);
        }
    }  
}
```

My problem is: when I set the common property in the constructor, works fine.
But when I´m setting the common property in `OnNavigatingTo` and using async, doesn´t work. The `SetProperty` is triggered when calling the `OnNavigatingTo`, but my binded label  with this common property doesn´t refresh the value.

```
namespace TaskMobile.ViewModels.Tasks
{
/// <summary>
/// Specific view model
/// </summary>
public class AssignedViewModel : BaseViewModel, INavigatingAware
{


    public AssignedViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService dialogService) : base(navigationService,dialogService)
    {
        CommonProperty= "Jorge Tinoco";  // This works
    }

    public async void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            Models.Vehicle Current = await App.SettingsInDb.CurrentVehicle();
            CommonProperty= Current.NameToShow; //This doesn´t works
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            App.LogToDb.Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I move my  `CommonProperty` from `BaseViewModel` to my  `AssignedViewModel ` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use SetProperty, you should not set value for the backfield.
so you should remove this line:

```
_common = value;
```

Comment: In fact, this will prevent the `OnPropertyChanged` event, because `SetProperty` won't see the new value as different from the old value (obviously)

Comment: Hi, @Mahdi Asgari.
Thanks for your help. Definitely that was my problem. 
 I dit not even notice  that line code.

Comment: Also, thanks to you @Haukinger for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing asynchronous invocation on a separate thread the UI is not being notified of the change.

The `async void` of `OnNavigatingTo`, which is not an event handler, means it is a fire and forget function running in a separate thread.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Create a proper event and asynchronous event handler to perform your asynchronous operations there

For example

```
public class AssignedViewModel : BaseViewModel, INavigatingAware {
    public AssignedViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService dialogService) 
        : base(navigationService, dialogService) {
        //Subscribe to event
        this.navigatedTo += onNavigated;
    }

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters) {
        navigatedTo(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
    }

    private event EventHandler navigatedTo = degelate { };
    private async void onNavigated(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        try {
            Models.Vehicle Current = await App.SettingsInDb.CurrentVehicle();
            CommonProperty = Current.NameToShow; //On UI Thread
        } catch (Exception e) {
            App.LogToDb.Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

That way when the awaited operation is completed the code will continue on the UI thread and it will get the property changed notification.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi. I appreciate your help.
For me, this looks like the long solution. Maybe would be easier if I put my common property in all my ViewModels. 
But, I don´t know if this would decrease my performance(at least a little bit)

What do you think?